# Why does LiveData only effect main layout and doesn't LiveData effect child layout UI in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

`FragmentHome` load layout_home.xml, and layout_home.xml displays a `recyclerview` and a button named `btnMain`

`recyclerview` include the item layout layout_voice_item.xml, it displays a button named `btnChild`。

I use `displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean>` to control whether both btnMain and btnChild are shown or not with the code `android:visibility="@{!aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"`.

I find `btnMain` can be shown or not when I change the value of displayCheckBox, but btnChild keep to show, why?

**FragmentHome.kt**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: LayoutHomeBinding

    private val mHomeViewModel by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            HomeViewModel(provideRepository(mContext))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.layout_home, container, false
        )
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.aHomeViewModel=mHomeViewModel

        val adapter = VoiceAdapters(mHomeViewModel)
        binding.mvoiceList.adapter=adapter
        mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
          adapter.submitList(it)
        }
        ...
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**HomeViewModel.kt**

```
class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _displayCheckBox = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
    val displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean> = _displayCheckBox

    fun setCheckBox(isDisplay:Boolean){
        _displayCheckBox.value = isDisplay
    }

    ...
}
```

**VoiceAdapters.kt**

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {
    ...
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VoiceViewHolder {
        return VoiceViewHolder(
            LayoutVoiceItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VoiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val aMVoice = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(aHomeViewModel, aMVoice)
    }

    inner class VoiceViewHolder (private val binding: LayoutVoiceItemBinding):
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(mHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel, aMVoice: MVoice) {
            binding.aHomeViewModel = mHomeViewModel
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

    }

    ...
}
class MVoiceDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MVoice>() {
    ...
}
```

**layout_home.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable name="aHomeViewModel"
            type="info.dodata.voicerecorder.viewcontrol.HomeViewModel" />
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mvoice_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout_voice_item"            
        />

      <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:visibility="@{!aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"            
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**layout_voice_item.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable name="aHomeViewModel"
        type="info.dodata.voicerecorder.viewcontrol.HomeViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChild"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="@{!aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"        
    />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Giving a `LifecycleOwner` to `LayoutVoiceItemBinding` might helps.

`voiceViewHolder.binding.lifecycleOwner = yourLifecycleOwner`

Answer (score 1):

The view holder pattern was not always part of android and before its wide adoption, a naive list implementation would have resulted in an inflated view rendered for each value in the submitted list. *That is extremely memory inefficient.*

With the adoption of a view holder pattern, views (the visual items) are only inflated up to the maximum that can be visible on the screen (and one or two extra for smooth scrolling)

The adapter however needs to be made aware of changes in the list's data.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#Adapter

> If the list needs an update, call a notification method on the
> RecyclerView.Adapter object, such as notifyItemChanged(). The layout
> manager then rebinds any affected view holders, allowing their data to
> be updated.

Observing the `displayCheckBox : LiveData<Boolean>` and calling `adapter.notifyItemChanged` might be the issue at hand.

I leave with another reference reiterating that view binding will not observe the live data but reduces the boilerplate code.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4

> What’s Left?
> All the boilerplate from the RecyclerView is now handled
> and all you have left to do is the hard part: loading data off the UI
> thread, notifying the adapter when there is a data change, etc.
> Android Data Binding only reduces the boring part.